# How to have a for loop program loop only 20 times?

Tags: java

My program so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Temperature 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int count = 20;
      double fahrenheit;
      double celsius;
      String input;

      // Scanner object for keyboard input.
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Get the information.
      System.out.print("Enter your starting temperature in Fahrenheit:  ");
      fahrenheit = kb.nextDouble();

      // Display the results in a table.
      System.out.println("Fahrenheit   Celsius");
      System.out.println("-----------------------");
      for (fahrenheit = fahrenheit; fahrenheit <= count; fahrenheit += 5)
      {
      // Calculate
      celsius = (fahrenheit - 32)*(5.0 / 9.0);
      System.out.printf("%,.2f \t\t\t %,.2f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
      }

   }
}
```

Now what I need it do is to produce a table of 20 temperature conversions from Fahrenheit to Celsius. 
If the User entered 0, here is a sample of the first 3 lines of what your output could look like:

FAHRENHEIT: 0      CELSIUS: -17.78

FAHRENHEIT: 5      CELSIUS: -15.00

FAHRENHEIT: 10    CELSIUS: -12.22

etc...

The problem is that it won't loop the correct amount of times if the input is more than 20.

Here is an example of what would happen if the user input 5:

**Output:**

Enter your starting temperature in Fahrenheit:  5

Fahrenheit      Celsius

5.00             -15.00

10.00            -12.22

15.00            -9.44

20.00            -6.67

And then that is where the output ends.

Does anyone know how I can make it so that the program will display 20 F to C equivalents no matter what the user inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1, add a counter and use it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++, fahrenheit += 5)
{
    // Calculate
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32)*(5.0 / 9.0);
    System.out.printf("%,.2f \t\t\t %,.2f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
}
```

Option 2, decrement `count` (and test against zero) while you loop.

```
for (; count > 0; count--, fahrenheit += 5)
{
    // Calculate
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32)*(5.0 / 9.0);
    System.out.printf("%,.2f \t\t\t %,.2f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is all messed up: `for (fahrenheit = fahrenheit; fahrenheit <= count; fahrenheit += 5)` it is comparing tempratures to a count (`fahrenheit <= count`).

If you always want 20 steps then something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ...
    fahrenheit  += 5;
}
```

would do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is keep a separate `index` that starts at 0 and goes up to 20. That means that there would be 2 variables being changed each time, `index` and `fahrenheit`, and the for-loop would look as follows:

```
int index = 0
for (fahrenheit = fahrenheit; index < count; fahrenheit += 5) {
    ...
    index++;
}
```